# Short circuited power supply still safe to use?

Tags: power-supply, current, short-circuit

Last night I short-circuited a Samsung 5v 1A phone charger to see how much current it could deliver. With my multimeter I measured 1.2A, despite the fact it says 1A. Is it possible I have damaged my charger, is it still safe to use? Furthermore, would it be safe to use at as a 24/7 power supply for something like a Raspberry Pi?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible that you have damaged it. But if you test it with something you don't care much about and it works, then it is probably OK.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the fact that I charged my phone with it overnight and an app reported that it was charging at 1200mA despite the 1A rating. Does this mean the power supply is fine?

Comment: Possible you've damaged it, but unlikely if it's a genuine Samsung; the big names tend to make their chargers properly.

Comment: Two things. That's not the right way to measure current, by just shorting it with a multimeter - so you won't get 5V while measuring amps so the result is irrelevant. The second thing is, we can't possibly answer if it is damaged or not, so your question is not answerable by anyone except someone who investigates your charger by taking it apart or testing it somehow. However, since it is a consumer product, and from a respectable brand, they most likely have some protection against people plugging in shorted wires or damaged devices that are shorted to the power supply.

Comment: @Justme thanks, I understand the question is a bit vague, I was just wondering that whether it outputting 1.2A when it says 1A means it's damaged. On a side note, how would I measure the max current?

Comment: @xTRA337 It is rated for 1A output at 5V. And most likely has some tolerance so that it can always provide 1A at 5V and overcurrent limit might be slightly higher. But when you short-circuited it with the multimeter, it was not outputing 5V, so all you know that your multimeter showed 1.2A in average, but in real life the power supply will see that the output is hopelessly short circuited and will hit overcurrent/undervoltage protections and shut down and restart, maybe a hundred times per second, which only averages to 1.2A which you see in the multimeter.

Comment: @xTRA337 substitute these words into your questions ... `will I get sick tomorrow?` ... now decide if your questions are answerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB chargers like these are flyback switchmode power supplies, they have inherent current limiting (as you've witnessed yourself). The charger is still fine and you can continue to use it.

A lot of smartphones also test the maximum current of a connected charger by successively increasing the current they draw until the charger goes into current-limiting mode. The chargers have to be built to survive this as it happens every time you plug in your phone.

1A might not be enough for a Raspberry Pi, though. There are official recommendations on chargers for the various Raspberry Pi models.

Comment: Thanks for that, It's a Pi Zero so it should be fine. Just curious, is the 1.2A normal for a charger that says 1A on it? My phone reported it was charging at 1200mA too with it.

Comment: Yes, good quality chargers always have some margin in their current limiting. And yeah, it should indeed be enough for a Pi Zero.